# Using G++-12 but still c++20 is still not supported

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, c++-concepts

I am using vs code where I run the task in the terminal with following option:

**g++-12 build active file**

**compiler: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/g++-12**

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 so I installed the g++-12 version using brew and after some manual setup in vs code I make the g++-12 to run the task along with I change the c++ standard to c++20 but still c++20 features are not supported

I check the version of c++ by below code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 202002L) std::cout << "C++20\n";
    else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
}
```

Output: c++17

I run the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

template <integral T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Add(5, 10): " << add(5, 10) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error occurred for this code is:

```
Executing task: C/C++: g++-12 build active file 

Starting build...
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/g++-12 -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "/home/abc/Desktop/d drive/c++ (Advance)/c++/concepts/concepts.cpp" -o "/home/abc/Desktop/d drive/c++ (Advance)/c++/concepts/concepts"
/home/abc/Desktop/d drive/c++ (Advance)/c++/concepts/concepts.cpp:17:11: error: 'integral' has not been declared
   17 | template <integral T>
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/home/abc/Desktop/d drive/c++ (Advance)/c++/concepts/concepts.cpp:18:1: error: 'T' does not name a type
   18 | T add(T a, T b)
      | ^
/home/abc/Desktop/d drive/c++ (Advance)/c++/concepts/concepts.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/home/abc/Desktop/d drive/c++ (Advance)/c++/concepts/concepts.cpp:30:31: error: 'add' was not declared in this scope
   30 |     cout << "Add(5, 10): " << add(5, 10) << endl;
      |                               ^~~

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: Try `-std=c++2a` option.

Comment: If you don't specify the C++ version that you want, g++ 12 will assume that you want C++17.  Adding `-std=c++20` to the command line will tell it to use C++20.

Comment: @Tanya Tomar It looks like you are reading the book "Exploring C++20".:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc.pdf `g++` 12.1 is defaulting to `-std=gnu++17`.

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is ‘-std=gnu++17’.

If you want C++20 you must specify `-std=c++20` or `-std=gnu++20` on the command line.